# My vectorize project isn't working. How would I go about fixing this

Tags: python, vectorization

```
class Document: 
    def __init__(self, doc_id):
        # create a new document with its ID
        self.id = doc_id
        # create an empty dictionary 
        # that will hold the term frequency (TF) counts
        self.tfs = {}

   def tokenization(self, text):
        # split a title into words, 
        # using space " " as delimiter
        words = text.lower().split(" ")
        for word in words: 
            # for each word in the list
            if word in self.tfs: 
                # if it has been counted in the TF dictionary
                # add 1 to the count
                self.tfs[word] = self.tfs[word] + 1
            else:
                # if it has not been counted, 
                # initialize its TF with 1
                self.tfs[word] = 1


    def save_dictionary(diction_data, file_path_name):
        f = open("./textfiles", "w+")

        for key in diction_data:
            # Separate the key from the frequency with a space and
            # add a newline to the end of each key value pair
            f.write(key + " " + str(diction_data[key]) + "\n")

        f.close()


    def vectorize(data_path):
        Documents = []
        for i in range(1, 21):
            file_name = "./textfiles/"+ i + ".txt"
            # create a new document with an ID
        doc = Document(i+1)
            #Read the files
        f = open(file_name)
        print(f.read())
            # compute the term frequencies
            #read in the files contents
        doc.tokenization(f.read())
            # add the documents to the lists
        Documents.append(doc)

     save_dictionary(doc.tfs, "tf_" + str(doc.id) + ".txt")

     DFS = {}
     for doc in Documents:
        for word in doc.tfs:
        DFS[word] = DFS.get(word,0) + 1

    save_dictionary(doc.DFS, "DFS_" + str(doc.id) + ".txt")


    vectorize("./textfiles")
```

So above is the code that I have and it isn't working. I added a nested loop for each word in the document's dictionary to do the following: If it does not appear in the dictionary for DF then add the word to the DF dictionary;

If it is already in the DF dictionary, increment its DF value by adding 1 to itself;

Then After all files are processed I call the save_dictionary()function again to save the DF dictionary to a file named df.txt in the same path with the input text files. Then vectorize.

When I run the code nothing happens so I definitely did something wrong somewhere any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your indentation in `vectorize` is wrong...

Comment: @RolandSmith Just how I copied the code over. I fixed it in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your indentation in multiple places is wrong. Please fix this first. For example, in `vectorize()`, `i` is referenced in the `doc` assignment yet it is outside the local scope of the for loop where `i` is defined.

Also, it would be helpful to separate your logic code from the script portion for easier debugging.

**UPDATE**:

`save_dictionary` and `vectorize()` either need `self` as the first function parameter to be part of the `Document` class or need the `@staticmethod` decorator. Also, `i` is still referenced outside of the for loop where it is only applicable. Changes to `vectorize` I would suggest are fixing indentation with respect to the for loop and using the `with` designation to create a context manager for properly and easily opening and closing files:

```py
def vectorize(self, data_path):
    Documents = []
    for i in range(1, 21):
        file_name = "./textfiles/"+ str(i) + ".txt"
        # create a new document with an ID
        doc = Document(i+1)
        #Read the files
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            # compute the term frequencies
            #read in the files contents
            doc.tokenization(text)
            # add the documents to the lists
        Documents.append(doc)
```

The context manager automatically closes the file when it exits the `with` context/indentation.

Comment: I am a bit confused with outside the local scope of the loop where i is defined. I am still new to this can you explain what that means.

Comment: Since `i` is defined when the for loop is declared, it can only be used inside the for loop and not after. The for loop can be considered the "local scope" that the `i` variable is part of. Once the for loop is exited, the `i` variable is no longer available for use. Does that make sense?

Comment: yea that makes sense. How would I go about fixing that? instead of i + 1 would it just be 1 or file_name + 1?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you some examples of what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for your help.